# get return value from async method

Tags: android, file-upload, android-asynctask

I am working in Android code.
try to use [qiniu SDK](http://developer.qiniu.com/code/v7/sdk/android.html) to upload image.

```
private String upload(String uploadToken, String picUrl) {

        final String[] uploadPicUrl = {null};
        UploadManager uploadManager = new UploadManager();
        data = <Filepath>
        String key = <filename>;
        String token = <toekn>;
        uploadManager.put(data, key, token,
        new UpCompletionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void complete(String key, ResponseInfo info, JSONObject res) {

           Log.i("qiniu", key + ",\r\n " + info + ",\r\n " + res);

           String fileKey = res.getString("key");
           uploadPicUrl[0]= filekey;
    }
}, null);

        Log.i("ws","---->>before return uploadPicUrl:" + uploadPicUrl[0]);
        return uploadPicUrl[0];
    }
```

This will return `null` because `put` execute in another thread, the `upload()` method may return before `put` execute complete.
But I want to return the value `fileKey` after the image upload complete.

Comment: Where is `upload ` method in Activity or normal class file?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK in Activity

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use the [CountDownLatch](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html). Initialize it to one before calling put, then decrement it in the put method completion handler and then wait for it in the code after the call to put.

However, just because you can do that does not mean you should. It would be very bad practice performance wise because you'd be stopping the UI thread while waiting on an IO event to complete. You might as well do the IO in the UI thread (which I believe will actually trigger an exception in some later versions of Android).

What you must do is structure your application such that it can handle the asynchronous behavior. You could have fileKey as an activity wide variable which is usually null and then becomes set when the put completion handler runs. Any other dependent operations get triggered after that as well.